# Moving tables between postgresql schemas without messing up Hasura schemas

Tags: postgresql, schema, migration

I have a database, which some teams are connecting to with their own Hasura instance.

I inherited a DB where everything is in the public schema, and I want to refactor it so that different parts of the database that aren't logically connected to each other are each in their own schema, and to ensure that user-defined objects and objects defined by extensions are never in the same schema.

Is there a way to automatically update the Hasura schema without changing the Hasura names of the tables? Since afaik when regenerating the schema, Hasura will prefix the schema name to the table name.